# Alert Text Before Save

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm still new in this language. I want to create alert text when users click certain button. However, I don't know how to do it. Anyone can help me on this. I provide some pictures for the idea.

Here is the example of the alert that I want to make

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried? Please edit your question and include your code attempt and explain what is not working.

Comment: `MsgBox "PLEASE CLICK AGAIN"`

Answer (score 0):

You can try below codes for alert message before doing any action.

```
Private Sub cmdSaveRecord_Click()    
    If MsgBox("Are you sure want to save?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Confirmation") = vbYes Then
        'Write code here to save your data
        RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
    Else
        'Write code here for cancallation
        MsgBox "Cancelled by user"
    End If    
End Sub
```